# Windows Azure Active Directory Auto password change

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to disable the auto password change in AAD?

All my app users get the change password request (after about two month from their registration)? Is there a way to avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Azure AD cmdlets to set a user's password to never expire:

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "myuser@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com" -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

You can download the cmdlets from here: http://aka.ms/aadposh (Be sure to follow the instructions, as it's a 2-step install).

Comment: Needless to say that setting this is not recommended on production accounts.

Comment: Thank you @Trondh. thought its gonna be easier with a checkbox from the admin panel that I didn't find... totally agree with you @DushyantGill!

Comment: We typically set the dirsync account's password to never change. Other than that, I completely agree.